# Extending or override GetRolesAsync method in Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Im using Asp.net Identity V2 on MVC 5 project.

Due to the nature of project , im trying to get List Of Custome Model

instead of String List from GetRolesAsync per userId. Is there any way

that i can Override this method to return my custome class , like the

one i is mapped to the table?

Also im using my own database layer and removed the EntityFrameWork part from Identity.

so there is no dbcontext.

this is my ApplicationUser :

```
public class ApplicationUser : UserInfo
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(IdentityStore.UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

UserStore Class :

```
  public class UserStore : Interfaces.IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, Interfaces.IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>
    {
        #region IUserStore
        public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    UserDAL.NewUser(user);
                });
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        public Task DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    UserDAL.DeleteUser(user);
                });
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
        {
            if (userId > 0)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return UserDAL.GetUser(userId);
                });
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userId");
        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return UserDAL.GetUserByUsername(userName);
                });
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        }

        public ApplicationUser FindByName(string userName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                return UserDAL.GetUserByUsername(userName);
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        }

        public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return UserDAL.UpdateUser(user);
                });
            }
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        }
        #endregion

        #region IUserRoleStore
        public Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    UserRoleDAL.NewUserRole(user.Id, roleName);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }
        }

        public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    UserRoleDAL.DeleteUserRole(user.Id, roleName);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }
        }

        public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    IList<string> roles = UserRoleDAL.GetUserRoles(user.Id);
                    return roles;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }
        }

        public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    IList<RoleInfo> roles = UserRoleDAL.GetUserRoles(user.Id);
                    foreach (RoleInfo role in roles)
                    {
                        if (role.Name.ToUpper() == roleName.ToUpper())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }
        }
        public IQueryable<UserInfo> Users => (UserDAL.GetUsers()).AsQueryable();

        #endregion
    }
```

UserRoleDAL Class:

```
public static int NewUserRole(int userID, string roleName)
    {
        List<ParameterInfo> parameters = new List<ParameterInfo>();
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "UserID", ParameterValue = userID });
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "RoleName", ParameterValue = roleName });
        int success = SqlHelper.ExecuteQuery("NewUserRole", parameters);
        return success;
    }

    public static int DeleteUserRole(int userID, string roleName)
    {
        List<ParameterInfo> parameters = new List<ParameterInfo>();
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "UserID", ParameterValue = userID });
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "RoleName", ParameterValue = roleName });
        int success = SqlHelper.ExecuteQuery("DeleteUserRole", parameters);
        return success;
    }

    public static IList<string> GetUserRoles(int userID)
    {
        List<ParameterInfo> parameters = new List<ParameterInfo>();
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "UserID", ParameterValue = userID });
        IList<string> roles = SqlHelper.GetRecords<string>("GetUserRoles", parameters);
        return roles;
    }

    public static UserInfo GetUserByUsername(string userName)
    {
        List<ParameterInfo> parameters = new List<ParameterInfo>();
        parameters.Add(new ParameterInfo() { ParameterName = "Username", ParameterValue = userName });
        UserInfo oUser = SqlHelper.GetRecord<UserInfo>("GetUserByUsername", parameters);
        return oUser;
    }

    public static List<RoleInfo> GetAllRole()
    {
        List<RoleInfo> oUser = SqlHelper.GetRecord<List<RoleInfo>>("GetAllRole",null);
        return oUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just add a custom interface between **UserStore** and **IUserStore** ?
I wrote a small example.

UserStore extended Interface:

```
public interface ICustomUserStore<TUser>: IUserStore<TUser>, Interfaces.IUserRoleStore<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    MyCustomClass GetCustomRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user);
}
```

New User Store Class:

```
public class UserStore : ICustomUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
 
    public MyCustomClass GetCustomRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var customRoles = UserRoleDAL.GetCustomUserRoles(user.Id);
                return customRoles;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
    }

    //Implement missing methods

}
```

UserRoleDAL Class:

```
public static MyCustomClass GetCustomUserRoles(int userID)
{
    var roles = new MyCustomClass();
    //Do stuff to populate your customRolesClass
   
    return roles;
}
```